# Classical solution satisfies weak formulation of Poisson equation

Tags: sobolev-spaces, poissons-equation

I have a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and the Poisson equation with Dirichelet boundary condition:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\nabla^2 u &= f\qquad in\ \Omega \\
u &= 0\qquad on\ \partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$
and I wanto to show that a solution $u$ satisfies the weak formulation, which to my understanding is
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \int_{\Omega} vf
$$
for all $v \in V = \{v \in \mathcal{H}^1(\Omega)| v = 0\ on\ \partial\Omega \}$, where $\mathcal{H}^1(\Omega)$ is the Sobolev space of functions with square integrable first derivative on $\Omega$.
The only thing I see is that $u \in V$, but I do not understand how having a classical solution can be used in the second equation. I thought I could substitute $-\nabla^2 u = f$, but I don't know how to get $-\nabla^2 u$ in the weak formulation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of that but $v=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ has no meaning **a priori** since any function in $H^{1}(\Omega)$ is defined almost everywhere and the measure of $\partial\Omega$ is $0$. However, it is overcome thanks to suitable properties of $\Omega$, where we require it to be a Lipschitz domain, if I am not mistaken. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $$\text{div} (v\nabla u) = \nabla v \nabla u + v \Delta u$$ and partial integration $$\int_\Omega \text{div}X = \int_{\partial \Omega} nX$$
together with $v=0 $ on $\partial \Omega$

(in case $\Omega$ does not satisfy the prerequisites of the divergence theorem you'll have to use an approximation argument)